# Django query - Database table to slow

Tags: django

I have a complex query that is just taking far too long. I think I have drilled down to the main problem when I execute:

```
Airplay.objects.all().count()
```

The execution time is: 48s
The results is: 37428412

The model is:

```
class Radio(Timestamps):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField('Slug', max_length=255, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.name, self.country)

class Airplay(Timestamps):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radio = models.ForeignKey(Radio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    airedAt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    playcount = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.song.name, self.radio.name)

class Timestamps(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

any ideas how to optimize this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Postgres is the db I'm using.

Comment: See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting - it's a database issue rather than a problem with Django. It should be better in Postgres 9.2 or higher.

Comment: I am on sql (PostgreSQL) 12.9 sho that's probably not the issues. Also other queries which include the Airplay table are also very slow.

Comment: There is a base class `Timestamps`. Could you repeat the test with directly inheriting from `models.Model`?

Comment: Timestamps is just an extension were 2 fields are added. I don't understand how this could slow things down.

I added it to the original question.